# Matchstick puzzle with roman numerals

Tags: matches

I got a puzzle from a book that asks to move one matchstick to get a valid equation. My "solutions"
feels like cheating... Does anyone have a good idea? The original equation, layed out with matches, is

> VI = V + VII

[image: the original picture. Sorry for the low quality]

Comment: Is the I made of 1 or 3 sticks?

Comment: It is only 1 stick

Comment: Please add the source of the puzzle

Comment: I don't have a source. It's a picture a friend showed me. And she made it a couple of days agoe in a mountain hut.

Comment: There appear to be further matches above/below the equation shown, but which don’t appear to relate to other equations... could they be relevant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Move the right most I so that it forms a square root sign with the right most V. So it looks something like this: $VI=V+\sqrt{1}$

Comment: That is a nifty idea.

Comment: Really nice one :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

> VII = V | VII (because 7=5|7, using bitwise |)

or:

> VI ≠ V + VI

Comment: Bitwise or is very clever. The ≠ trick doesn't work because you don't have a valid equation

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Zero) (emphasis added):

> #### Zero
>
> The number [zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28number%29) does not have its own Roman numeral, but the word *nulla* (the [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) word meaning "none") was used by medieval scholars in lieu of 0. [Dionysius Exiguus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysius_Exiguus) was known to use *nulla* alongside Roman numerals in 525.<sup>[[32]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#cite_note-zero-32)[[33]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#cite_note-zero-33)</sup> **About 725, [Bede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede) or one of his colleagues used the letter N, the initial of *nulla* or of *nihil* (the Latin word for "nothing"), in a table of [epacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epacts), all written in Roman numerals.**<sup>[[34]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#cite_note-zero-34)</sup>

Therefore:

> Move the final `I` to the front of the second `V` such that it forms an (italicised) `N` and one gets:
>
> ```
> VI = N + VI
> ```
>
> Which, in Arabic numerals, Bede (at very least) would have considered to be:
>
> ```
> 6 = 0 + 6
> ```

Comment: Awesome first answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

> From: the right stroke of the right most V
> To: intersect with the I on the right. 
> Outcome: VI=V+IxI (take x as multiplication sign)

Comment: These puzzles allow for some lateral thinking, but usually a slanted line cannot be a 1

Comment: I also though about something like that. But then the 1 is not really a 1.

Answer (score 1):

> Take the matchstick that makes the final `I`, snap it in two, and place each half beneath the initial `V` to create an `X`.  You’d therefore have:
>
> ```
> XI = V + VI
> ```
>
> Which, in Arabic numerals, is of course the valid equation:
>
> ```
> 11 = 5 + 6
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> moving the second I in VII so it turns the equal sign equal to a less than or equal sign (VI is less than or equal to V + VI)

Comment: Then you wouldn't have "a valid equation"!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer-ish

> Looking at the first V, if you take the right match and cross it over the first match, you get `XI = V + VII` or `11 = 5 + 7`

Comment: That equation isn't correct, though.

Comment: Yeah, still working on it...